# Angular 14 - Getting data out of angular material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-template

I'm looking to get data out from my material dialog that uses a ng-template. I'm getting a Property 'data' does not exist on type 'MeetingsComponent'. when trying to use this line.

```
<button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>Save</button>
```

This is my full code for the template:

```
<ng-template #editMeeting>
    <mat-dialog-content>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Meeting Name</mat-label>
            <input #name matInput type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Meeting Location</mat-label>
            <input #location matInput type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
            <input #date matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
            <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
        <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>Save</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

This line is called to open dialog:

```
<button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="edit(editMeeting, row)">Edit</button>
```

And this is the edit function being called:

```
  edit(content: any, row: any): void {
    this.matDialog.open(content, {
      data: {name: row.name}
    })
    console.log(row)
  }
```

I know this isn't the best way to render dialog content, but just for speed right now, this is the way I'm doing it. Let me know if I left out any needed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dialog component, you need to declare data object to receive from parent in component's constructure.

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { ...}
```

Full example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-rd7fnm?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for help, but with this code I'm getting lots of errors from my html template now. I use the `` to wrap my template html and even tried to straight copy past your code of the entire example dialog component but I'm getting errors like "Can't bind to 'mat-dialog-close' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. A whole load of other errors like 'mat-datepicker' is not a known element. So I'm not too sure if this works in Angular 14, as that stackblitz is in angular 6 I believe

Comment: Already add the dialog component to `declarations` and `entryComponents` in `.module.ts` ?

Comment: I actually found the solution and it this was a part of it. I followed the matdialog documentation line for line.